# How to remove all re.findall matches from the inputed text, in Python?

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

I think it should be like that, but it's not working.

```
import re

RNA = input("")
regex = r"gu(?:\w{0,}?)ag"
introns = re.findall(regex, RNA)
exons = re.sub(introns, '', RNA)
print(exons)
```

But it should delete all matches that were found by the re.findall, or replace it with an empty space or other texts.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input you have and the output you want?

Comment: input = aaatguttttttagtaaaaa
output = aaattaaaaa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the call to `re.findall()`, you can call `re.sub` with a regex and all occurrences will be replaced

```
import re

RNA = input("")
regex = r"gu(?:\w{0,}?)ag"
exons = re.sub(regex, '', RNA)
print(exons)
```

Comment: Exactly. `re.findall` returns a list with all occurrences of what you want to replace.

Comment: @Iain Shelvington, many thanks.
I'm just beginning to using a regular expression in python. If you know, can you please give links to some good guides about it?
https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html - for me it`s a little bit kinky.
But the other documentations and guides seem incomplete or had not enough examples for understanding.

Comment: @OrkBiotechnologist The how-to guide in the python docs is okay... https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html. Regular expressions and their use is a bit of a dark art in almost all languages, I don't know of another guide that I would recommend. Sorry!